# How can I retrieve the lines Passenger gave me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

this question is certainly newbie-generated. When I installed Apache and Passenger to work I received 3 lines of code to add to the apache2.conf file on etc/apache2 path, but because of an authorization reason I couldn't add those lines to the file. I want to know, how can I retrieve these lines?

P.S. Passenger Gem Version is 2.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the installation again then it won't do any harm.

It's probably something like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5
PassengerRuby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

- [PassengerRoot](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerroot_lt_directory_gt) directive
- [PassengerRuby](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) directive

—Note that the `PassengerRuby` directive in my example above is for Mac OS X.

Comment: Why don't you just re-run the installer?

Comment: yeah.. but I remember.. I have the access denied to the file apache2.conf, I could open the file but not change it,but I'm the admin. Bcz of this that I didin't put these lines into the file =(

Comment: So you can view the file’s contents but not modify it? Where are you going to put the lines if you get them?!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I've just uninstalled and reinstalled the Passenger Gem and retyped **passenger-install-apache2-module** and got the lines I've missed =)

For the ones whose PCs are also Ubuntu and had this same trouble, there are the lines:

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8

Considering I'm with Ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope, Apache2 and Passenger Gem version 2.2.5 =)

Salutes!